# How would you call someone who puts all their effort into their job

Tags: word-request

When people in interviews sometimes they ask you to describe yourself in 3 words.
If you want to say that you really do what you do well, and put all your time and efforts into it, you would be a _____ person.

Comment: You could start with adding a spelling checker into your browser ;)

Answer (score 2):

The kind of person you're talking about is generally called a [**diligent**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/diligent) person. If you're diligent in what you do, you do it with great care and effort. For example:

> He never slacks off at work because he's a **diligent** and hardworking guy.

Another similar word that you might find interesting would be [**industrious**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/industrious). This word is just a synonym for *hardworking*.

Answer (score 0):

A very straightforward way of describing these kind of people would be **hard-working**.

Answer (score 0):

There's the noun "**[eager beaver](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eager%20beaver)**" ([*Urban Dictionary*](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Eager%20Beaver)),

Surely, the most common term is "**[hard worker](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/hard+worker)**" *(or "**hard-worker**")* - *one who is industrious and diligent in carrying out tasks or duties*.

As an adjective you can use "*hard-working*", "*diligent*", "*industrious*", "*assiduous*", and "*committed*" all of which work in similar way.

In your example I would definitely use "**diligent**".